# Changing button colors with JQM and addClass only works once per page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to change the background of a button for a mobile app.  The Click event seems too slow, so I used vmousedown.  This works but only once per page.  I'm doing this.

```
Mousedown
$(.headerNavBar).on('vmousedown','.logout',function() {
$(this).removeClass('ui-bar-c').addClass('ui-bar-c');
});
Mouse UP
$(.headerNavBar).on('vmouseup','.logout',function() {
$(this).removeClass('ui-bar-c');
});
$(.headerNavBar).on('tap','.logout',function() {
$(this).removeClass('ui-bar-c');
});
```

HTML is

```
<li><a href="#" class="logout" data-icon="back" data-theme="b">Log out</a></li>
```

The button is in a JQueryMobile page content block.

If there is a better way to just change the background gradient that would be fine too.

Update: I just noticed in the inspector that the class is being added and removed, it's just not updating on the page.

Comment: can you change `vmousedown` to `mousedown` ?

Comment: It didn't make any difference, nothing did.  I think it's because it's a navbar which changes the color scheme anyway with ui-btn-active.  So I just made a custom CSS block for .header .ui-btn-active with the color I wanted and removed ui-btn-active on click and on response to my dialog, like cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Use parent element or document to bind the event and give the selector. Second thing you may check you have vmousedown it would be mousedown and same for vmouseup.

**Mousedown**

```
$(document).on('vmousedown','.logout', function() {
   $(this).removeClass('ui-bar-c').addClass('ui-bar-c');
});
```

**Mouse UP**

```
$(document).on('vmouseup','.logout', function() {
      $(this).removeClass('ui-bar-c');
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work yet, still only changes once.  When I step through it using Chrome the vmouseup doesn't seem to remove the class.  This is the same for my method also.

Comment: Why you have vmousedown and vmouseup instead of mousedown and mouseup ?

Comment: It's just what the JQMobile docs said to use.  It's for a mobile app.  I'll try the normal ones though.

Comment: I added what I think is the parent element, now the button doesn't work at all though.  It's in <div><ul><li><button class="logout">  Which is the parent there?  li or ul or div?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').delegate('.logout','vmousedown', function() {
   $(this).removeClass('ui-bar-c').addClass('ui-bar-c');
});
```